# Implementing activity how to use methods in jar in android

Tags: android, api, jar

i am creating  own framework api (telephone services related api) i am creating one library app  this library app to create myjar.jar  i am developing another application just i am adding asset folder this myjar.jar  and configure this jar adding buildpath 
in coding importing the package

this application run into real device:

```
MacTesting mp = new MacTesting();
mp.getMacAddress();
Log.v("1111","this is mac add"+ mp.getMacAddress());
```

result is null

```
public class MacIdTesting extends Activity implements Parcelable
{
    public static final String KEY_WIFI_MAC_ADDRESS = null;

    public  static final String READ_PHONE_STATE = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
       public String mMacAddress;
       public String phonenumber;
       void setMacAddress(String macAddress) {
           this.mMacAddress = macAddress;
       }

       public String getMacAddress() {
           return mMacAddress;
       }
       public String getLine1Number() 
       {
       ContextWrapper mContext = null;
       mContext.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(READ_PHONE_STATE, "Requires READ_PHONE_STATE");
           MacIdTesting mPhone = null;
        return mPhone.getLine1Number();
       }

      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
      {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = manager.getConnectionInfo();
        String MACAddress = wifiInfo.getMacAddress(); 
        System.out.println("macsddress "+MACAddress);
       }

    @Override
    public int describeContents()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;


    }
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dest.writeString(mMacAddress);  
    }
}
```

see this screenshot
[image]

how can solve this problem

Comment: It looks more like you have an issue in MacTesting, not in including your Jar file.

Comment: What is `null`? `mp` or `mp.getMacAddress()`?

Comment: mp.getMacAddress() is null already i am imported jar file this method is see this library jar file

Comment: i am update screenshot link  above question

Comment: Please post the code from getMacAddress()

Comment: please give me suggestion this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is an activity and has onCreate method, but not a constructor.

I change the onCreate method to be a constructor like that (and remove the `extends activity`):

```
 public MacIdTesting(Context ctx) 
      {
        WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = manager.getConnectionInfo();
        mMacAddress = wifiInfo.getMacAddress();
       }
```

And call it from the activity like that:

```
MacTesting mp = new MacTesting(this);
```

Also, I would keep `private` members instead of `public` (`private String mMacAddress`).

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues:

- `MacIdTesting` is an Activity but you use it the `AndroidMac` class which is an Activity by itself. Therefore the lifecycle methods of `MacIdTesting` will not get called. You can for example `AndroidMac` let extend `MacIdTesting`. Then you could call `getMacAddress()`.
- The code in `MacIdTesting` is faulty: You are assigning the MAC address to some local variable and the field in the object never gets set.
- Before writing a library I would suggest to read more about the android lifecycle and possibly about Java.

Comment: see the above screenshot  how can create jar file  this jar how can using another class please give me suggestion

Answer (score 0):

add

```
this.mMacAddress = MACAddress;
```

as the last line to the onCreate() method of MacTesting.